# Get table row by row index jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to access row in my table using the row index.

When I try to get the row by is index I get :

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This is my code:

```
function moveUpMuscle(muscleIdFrom, muscleOrderFrom, index)
{

    if(index == 0)
    {
        alert("Muscle is already at the top of the list");
        return;
    }

    table = $("#muslce_order_table");

    console.log(table == null ? "null" : "not null");

    row = table.rows(index);

    muscleIdTo = row.attr("data-id");
    muscleOrderTo = row.attr("data-order");

    console.log("muscleIdFrom " + muscleIdFrom + " muscleOrderFrom " + muscleOrderFrom);
    console.log("muscleIdTo " + muscleIdTo + " muscleOrderTo " + muscleOrderTo);

}
```

The error points to this line:

```
 row = table.rows(index);
```

In my console the log is "not null" so the `table` element is not undefined.

Comment: I think you misspelt `muscle` `$("#muslce_order_table");`

Comment: `rob = $('somestuffwhichnotthere'); console.log(rob == null);` gives `false`

Comment: Try `row = table.find('tr').eq(index);`

Comment: Please take a look at the selector documentation (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and the jquery API in general (http://api.jquery.com/), it'll tell you very quicky that `rows` is not a jQuery method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.rows` is not a jQuery method. Change your code to retrieve the row as follows

```
row = table.find('tr').eq(index);
```